# Sudo commands just go to newline

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, sudo

When entering sudo commands, my system sometimes arbitrarily doesnt execute the command but goes to a newline.

For instance, typing `sudo apt-get update` and hitting enter just goes to a blank newline where I can carry on typing.

When I reset my machine, two out of five times it goes back to normal which is quite baffling given that I dont really change anything between resets.

Can anyone provide any insights as to why my system does this?

I am using the Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for the ask ubuntu forum so I will be asking it there

Comment: Did the `sudo` command somehow get overridden or redefined? What does `type sudo` report (it will show what bash thinks `sudo` means)? Does `/usr/bin/sudo` work when plain `sudo` fails?

Comment: When I query type sudo I get the following response: "sudo is /usr/bin/sudo"

Comment: That's normal. Is `sudo` failing right now? If it isn't, try that again when it starts failing, and see if you get a different result.

Comment: Yeah its failing now and I tried that command whilst it is failing

Comment: My next guess would be that `sudo` is hanging while trying to get your user info, or something like that. I'm not familiar enough with Linux to have a good idea how to troubleshoot further, but maybe someone else does.

Comment: Okay well thanks for the attempt Gordon. It is highly frustrating that I am experiencing such an issue on a reputably robust system. One wonders if this is a Linux or Ubuntu issue... I would guess the latter

Comment: Hey Gordon, check my own answer below - its the most freak glitch ive encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a hard format of the latest Ubuntu distro, the error persisted. It was impossible that such a rare and fundamental command line glitch could persist across a new reformat and installation and so I began to suspect hardware. **The error was a wifi USB plugin. Disconnecting it from the USB port resolved not only this, but other latent glitches including Ubuntu not powering down and various apps not opening.**

Comment: That really is weird. Can you name (& shame) the USB device?

Comment: Not sure SO allows link sharing here it is: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dodocool%C2%AE-Wireless-Adapter-150Mbps-10-7-10-10/dp/B01EAGWDBS

dodocool® Wireless USB Adapter Wi-Fi Dongle AC